# Include a metabox in the 'home' screen of a custom post type? If not, then the dashboard page?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have a page with a simple YouTube embed. I would like the client to be able to easily switch the video id from the dashboard without having to edit any templates.

Something like this: `<iframe width="576" height="324" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?=$video_id ?>"></iframe>`

So I'm trying to insert a metabox in the home page of the respective custom post type (see below) but am not sure how to go about it.

[image]

Is something like this possible? If not, is there a way to insert a metabox into the 'home' dashboard page of the WordPress dashboard? I'm open to any suggestions as well. Thank you.
- Update -

This is what I currently have in my functions.php:

```
// YouTube Metabox
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'custom_dashbox');

function custom_dashbox() {
  global $wp_meta_boxes;
  wp_add_dashboard_widget('widget_slug','Featured Video', 'widget_display','widget_submission');
}

function widget_display() {
  echo '<label><small>YouTube ID</small></label><br /><br /><input type="text" name="youtube_id" /><br/><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit_youtube" />';
}

function widget_submit() {
  //Do what you need to do with your youtube id possibly:
  if (get_option('youtubeid'))
  {
    update_option('youtubeid',$_POST['youtube_id']);
  }
  else {
    add_option('youtubeid',$_POST['youtube_id']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify a bit... Do you want to allow the client to add a different video ID for each "Furniture" post?  Or do **all** your furniture posts use a single template that has a video embedded and the client chooses a single ID for all furniture posts?

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified this. No, not a different id for each post. There will only be one video in total at the top of the page. It'll be sort of a featured video. The client will only be featuring one video at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I haven't actually done this yet, it is something I was looking into, so please let me know how it goes.

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'custom_dashbox');

```
    function custom_dashbox() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    wp_add_dashboard_widget('widget_slug','Widget Name', 'widget_display','widget_submission');
    }

    function widget_display() {
    echo '<input type="text" name="youtube_id" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit_youtube" />';
    }

function widget_submit() {
//Do what you need to do with your youtube id possibly:
if (get_option('youtubeid'))
{
update_option('youtubeid',$_POST['youtube_id']);
}
else {
add_option('youtubeid',$_POST['youtube_id']);
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried playing around with this and the widget shows up fine in my dashboard but I can't get it to save. I am not too skilled with php so I feel I may be missing something obvious. I've updated the original post with what I have right now in my functions.php.